# Adapt an imported layer to the size of the browser window

Tags: openlayers

In openlayers 4
I have several layers wmts ign and an other imported from a mapserver.
The first adapt to the size of the browser but that of the map server is displayed only if I fix width and height of the map.
The css

```
html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
    #map {
    height: 100%;
    }
```

If I set the width of the map to 768px it appears, but not if I put it at 900px

```
#map {
Height: 100%;
Width: 768px;
}
```

And the call of the layer is made via

```
var emprises_operations_inrap = new ol.layer.Image({
        title: 'operations Inrap',
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
          url: 'http://10.210.1.32:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\\ms4w\\map\\fond_mapserver_ol3.map',
          params: {'LAYERS': 'emprises',
                    //'CRS': 'EPSG:2154',
                    'FORMAT': 'image/png'},
          serverType: 'mapserver',
          extent: [93501.1, 6044342.00, 1248133.25, 7115784.50]
        })
      });
```

Then how do you also adapt it to the size of the window?

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, I find the solution
an ol.layer.Tile instead of a ol.layer.Image

```
var emprises_operations_inrap =   new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'operations Inrap',
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
          url: 'http://10.210.1.32:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\\ms4w\\map\\fond_mapserver_ol3.map',
          params: {LAYERS: 'emprises', TILED: true,  FORMAT: 'image/png'},
          serverType: 'mapserver'
        })
      })
```